# IOException with BufferedReaders and InputStreamReaders

Tags: java, inputstreamreader

I am modding [Minicraft](http://playminicraft.com), and I am running into a bit of trouble using `BufferedReader`s.  

So in my mod, I have a class called `FuncResource` in which I define a way to execute a custom method when an item is used.
In the `Resource` vanilla class, I define multiple objects of this type.  For example, a console object which lets you change your gamemode.

Here is the `interact` method I am using in the console item class:

```
public boolean interact(Tile tile, Level level, int x, int y, Player player, int direction)
{
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String input = "";

    System.out.print("> ");

    try
    {
        input = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Input error...  :/");
    }

    String[] commandList = input.split(" ");

    if(commandList[0].equals("gamemode"))
    {
        player.gamemode = Integer.parseInt(commandList[1]);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now here's the problem: Using the console item once, it's fine.  I change my gamemode.  HOWEVER, when I use it every time after that, it always throws an `IOException`.  Every single time.


Am I doing something wrong?  Have I messed up the input somehow?  Please help - I've read the JavaDocs and they didn't help, and I'm an amateur at Java.

If you need more information, just ask.


EDIT: I took people's advice and removed the `reader.close();` code.  HOWEVER, I tried it again and it printed this stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at com.mojang.ld22.item.resource.funcitems.ConsoleItem.interact(ConsoleItem.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mojang.ld22.item.resource.FuncResource.interactOn(FuncResource.java:31)
    at com.mojang.ld22.item.ResourceItem.interactOn(ResourceItem.java:53)
    at com.mojang.ld22.entity.Player.attack(Player.java:177)
    at com.mojang.ld22.entity.Player.tick(Player.java:118)
    at com.mojang.ld22.level.Level.tick(Level.java:274)
    at com.mojang.ld22.Game.tick(Game.java:221)
    at com.mojang.ld22.Game.run(Game.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that points to the line of code that caused the error?

Comment: There's lots of reasons it might throw an exception. Have you considered actually printing the exception using something like `e.printStackTrace()` for example

Comment: Hm.  One second, I'll print the stack trace...

Comment: Printed the stack trace.  I don't know why on Earth it's throwing that error, though...  Why would the stream be closed?

Comment: Since eventually someone will mention [CloseShieldInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) I will go ahead and post a comment :D. Just wrap `System.in` with it and close the `Scanner` as intended.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, I have no idea what that is.  BUT, I will go ahead, look it up, and try to use it anyways.

Comment: Actually, @AnthonyAccioly, I want to do this without any external libraries.  Sorry.

Comment: If you are still getting the exception, verify you aren't closing the stream somewhere else and also make sure you've truly recompiled the code.

Comment: I have really truly recompiled the code.  `reader` is a local variable, and I have searched and double-searched my file twice over, and there is no reference to the stream being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try
{
    input = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Input error...  :/");
}
```

Don't close this reader because it contains `System.in` which should remain open.

Comment: Did you mean to edit this code? Because you're still closing System.in here.

Comment: I'm quoting it to comment on it. Of course, `reader.close()` should be removed to fix the code.

Answer (score 3):

Closing your reader will close the underlying stream; closing System.in is, in general, bad, as you can imagine.

As a general rule, if you opened something, close it; but if you didn't, don't. Here: don't'.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work, but suddenly it did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember what I did, but I solved it.  I had removed the `reader.close();` statement and it still wasn't working properly, but just one time it simply worked.  I don't know how or why, but thanks to all who helped.